# how to start a map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to add a map node to my robot but I don't where to put it, this is my launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/willowgarage_world.launch">
  </include>
  <param name="robot_description" command="cat '$(find robot)/urdf/robot.xacro'"/>
  
  <arg name="x" default="0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0.5"/>
  
  <node name="robot_spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen"
      args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z)" />
      
<!-- send fake joint values -->
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
  <param name="use_gui" value="False"/>
</node>

<!-- Combine joint values -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
<!-- Show in Rviz   -->
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" />

</launch>
```

when I start a rviz and add map I get the message "No map received" what should I do now?

and when use

```
rostopic list
```

I am getting these topics

```
/clicked_point
/clock
/cmd_vel
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/initialpose
/joint_states
/move_base_simple/goal
/odom
/robot/laser/scan
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375144/how-to-start-a-map/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2021-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you already have a map in YAML format and as an PGM file (or other compatible format)  you need to run [map_server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) to publish the map on a ros topic.

To add it to your launch file include this:

```
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find your_package_name)/map/your_map_name.yaml"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2021-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-04-02**:
I don't have a YAML file. how should I create one?

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2021-04-03**:
See @tryan 's answer on how to create a map.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many SLAM packages and tutorials for how to use them.  I suggest following one of those to start.  Here are a couple examples to get you going, but some quick searching will turn up others:

1. [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)
2. [hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam)

Here's a good resource for [simulation and SLAM with a turtlebot](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/).  If you successfully complete the tutorial(s) and inspect the files, you should be able to transfer that knowledge to your own robot, but if you run into issues, feel free to post a new question.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1